# Question on Rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with $\operatorname{rank}(A) = k$, what is the rank of ($\lambda A$) for some $\lambda  \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

I think since $\lambda$
 is just a scalar it won't affect the rank of the matrix, so the answer is still $k$ ?

Comment: any thoughts about the question? have you tried some example?

Comment: Think about the kernel of $\lambda A$ and use a relation between dimensions of kernel and of image.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I think since $\lambda$ is just a scalar it won't affect the rank of the matrix, so the answer is still k ?

Comment: it is usually advisable to include your own thoughts and attempts when you post question on this site, hence I have included your response into the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Good guess so far.

However, don't forget the special case where $\lambda =0$, of which case, the problem become what is the rank of $0\cdot A=0$.

When $\lambda \neq 0$, solution of $(\lambda A)x=0$ and the solution of $Ax=0$ is the same. That is the kernel is the same. By rank-nullity theorem, the rank remains the same, which is $k$.